# Difference between chastise and lambaste?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Is there a difference between chastise and lambaste?
When should one use chastise and when should one use lambaste?

Comment: The words are synonyms according to MW.

Comment: http://www.vocabulary.com/lists/836305#view=notes

Answer (score 1):

*Chastise* means to rebuke or reprimand someone. *Lambaste* means to criticize someone. Though listed as synonyms, they don't mean the same thing in all contexts.

> She chastised her brother for his laziness.
>
> He chastised his son for not behaving well in front of the guests. *Means punish here*
>
> They lambasted the paper for its lack of research.

Comment: The OP seems to have suspected as much. Now, what **more** can we add to what the OP already knows? **Why** and **how** are they different?

Comment: could you please give example statements?

Comment: @Newtoembedded added.